# Spring Data JPA : can't read updated value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We're using SpringBoot and its spring data JPA, but something wired occur:

We have two different service here :

ServiceA :

```
ConsumerBalance consumerBalance = consumerBalanceRepository.findByConsumerId(consumerId);

// original consumer balance is 3.0
// update balance, e.g. balance = 4.0

// then save consumerBalance to data base using JPARepository.save
```

ServiceB:

```
// After the operation ServiceA, we execute ServiceB
ConsumerBalance consumerBalance = consumerBalanceRepository.findByConsumerId(consumerId);

// print consumerBalance, the result is still 3.0, not the updated value 4.0
```

Service Transaction annotation:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ConsumerBalanceServiceImpl implements ConsumerBalanceService
```

JAPRepository:

```
public interface ConsumerBalanceRepository extends JpaRepository<ConsumerBalance,Long>{

ConsumerBalance findByConsumerId(Long consumerId);
```

#### UPDATE

They are in different transactions, ServiceB is execute after ServiceA commits, and After ServiceA, the updated data is actually flush to database(I use breakpoints to check that)

#### UPDATE

Data update code

```
ConsumerBalance consumerBalance = consumerBalanceRepository
                .findByConsumerId(consumerId);
        if (null == consumerBalance) {
            consumerBalance = new ConsumerBalance();
            // something not cool
            consumerBalance.setVersion(1);
            consumerBalanceRepository.save(consumerBalance);
        }
```

Any idea ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please add the code that's doing the actual value updating and saving, as opposed to comments describing it.

Comment: Is it the same transaction, or different? If ServiceB executes before ServiceA commits, this is to be expected.

Comment: @mavarazy They are in different transactions, ServiceB is execute after ServiceA commits, and After ServiceA, the updated data is actually flush to database(I use breakpoints to check that)

Comment: @MrROY are you using some cache mechanism in Spring? You query DB and the value is 4, right?

Comment: @mavarazy yes, After ServiceA executed, the value is turned to 4, but ServiceA still get a 3.0 in the program, wired !

Comment: a flush isn't a commit. Also your updated code is flawed, you are checking for `null` if it is null save and update version (which you generally shouldn't be doing). But how are you going to set something on a `null` object? And when it is found, nothing is going to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use `saveAndFlush` instead of `save`?

For example:

```
ConsumerBalance consumerBalance = consumerBalanceRepository
                .findByConsumerId(consumerId);
if (null == consumerBalance) {
   // something not cool
consumerBalance.setVersion(1);
consumerBalanceRepository.saveAndFlush(consumerBalance);
}
```

Also, do you have cache on services? If yes, you also need to flush cache.

Comment: Hi, I've tried saveAndFlush, and I never use cache on services.